# Racemic mixture of meso compound

Tags: stereochemistry

My solution manual implied that we can have a racemic mixture of a meso compound.

Is this possible?

I was able to rotate the molecule to make it symmetrical. Sure, the bromination in the nucleophilic solvent gives you an anti product, but from my understanding, if you can rotate the molecule so that it is symmetrical, the molecule can be meso.

I'm thinking no because meso compounds by definition have no enantniomers and a racemic mixture has both enantiomers.

Comment: This question and answer highlight what is sadly too often the case - solutions manuals are not edited very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct and you enumerated the reasons why.  A racemic mixture is a mixture of *d* and *l* enantiomers in equal proportion.  A meso compound has no *d* or *l* isomers, it is achiral.